# Switching power supply simulation problem

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, proteus

I'm building a 5V power supply using MC34063 IC. Before I build a prototype, I want to simulate it in Proteus to see if everything works correctly. Here is the schematic:
[image]

It is done according to the datasheet for the IC (page 7), which can be found here:
https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF

Transformer is 10:1.
However, when I start the simulation I cannot finish it (whole thing goes off after simulation of 100msec). Is there something wrong with the schematic? Thank you for help!

Comment: what do you mean `whole thing goes off`?

Comment: Have you set your simulation to stop on steady state?

Comment: This is a classic: you try to simulate a switching converter operating at a 100-kHz switching frequency while the input is a 60-Hz ac line. You can imagine how many high-frequency switching cycles of 10-µs duration it will take before you see a rectified dc voltage biasing the buck converter. The solution is to get rid of the front-end rectifier and replace \$C_1\$ with a dc source equal to the rectified voltage. It should be much faster now. If you truly want to simulate the whole thing, make sure first the dc-dc is ok and don't save data before several hundreds of ms.

Comment: @VerbalKint Ok, when at the input there is dc source, everything works correctly. Anyway, the power supply part (meaning transofrmer+rectifier+filtering cap) seems to be fine regarding input for the MC34063? If not, how should it be designed? Unfortunately I couldn't find any reliable schematics on the internet (with switching power supply ICs)...

Comment: @jsotola Proteus can't finidh the simulation (it stops at several msecs)